# ERROR with my Ubuntu: Cannot open the disk 'D:\My Documents\My Virtual Machines\Ubuntu\Ubuntu-1.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, vmware-workstation

Cannot open the disk 'D:\My Documents\My Virtual Machines\Ubuntu\Ubuntu-1.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.

Reason: The physical disk is already in use.

======================

When I powered on my Ubuntu on VMwave, a window showed up within words above.
I tried to remove the old hard disk in settings and created a new one, but it still doesnot work.

Has someone solved this problem? PLEASE do me a favour!!Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're *sure* it's not in use, I think from memory that VMWare protects them with `*.lock` files in the same directory as the VMDK files.

So you could try deleting the lock files **after backing up the directory first!!!**

But:

1. I'm not entirely certain this is a *programming* question; and
2. I'm not entirely certain I'm right :-)

So I've marked it community wiki and voted to move your question to SuperUser (you may also want to hassle the bods at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: THX for your answer first!!! I tried to delete the .lck files even the doc.BUT ......